# OSError: Failed to interpret file '/modelvgg.npy' as a pickle

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I used a pretrained imagenet VGG16 model in keras and add my own Dense on top.
I'm trying to save and load weights from the model i have trained.

the code im using to save the model is

```
import time
start = time.time()
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_batches,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
                              #callbacks=callbacks_list,
                              validation_data=valid_batches,
                              validation_steps=steps_valid,
                               shuffle=True)
end = time.time()
model.save("modelvgg.npy")
```

Let me know if this an incorrect way to do it,or if there is a better way to do it.

but when i try to load them,using this,

```
 def __init__(self, vgg16_npy_path=None, trainable=True):
    if vgg16_npy_path is None:
        path = inspect.getfile(Vgg16)
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))
        path = os.path.join(path, "modelvgg.npy")
        vgg16_npy_path = path
        print(path)

    self.data_dict = np.load(vgg16_npy_path, encoding='latin1').item()
    self.trainable = trainable
    print("npy file loaded")
```

but i get this error:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
446             try:
--> 447                 return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
448             except Exception:

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'H'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d099900e8f3b> in <module>
 46         labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 2])
 47 
---> 48         vgg = vgg16.Vgg16()
 49         model.build(images)
 50         cost = (-1) * tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(labels, tf.log(model.prob)), axis=1)

~/Bureau/Grad-CAM_final/model/vgg16.py in __init__(self, vgg16_npy_path, trainable)
 18             print(path)
 19 
---> 20         self.data_dict = np.load(vgg16_npy_path, encoding='latin1').item()
 21         self.trainable = trainable
 22         print("npy file loaded")

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
448             except Exception:
449                 raise IOError(
--> 450                     "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
451     finally:
452         if own_fid:

OSError: Failed to interpret file '/home/omri/Bureau/Grad-CAM_final/model/modelvgg.npy' as a pickle
```

Any suggestions on what i may be doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Keras doesn't save models in pickle or numpy formats, it uses HDF5 for this.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  how can i save in pickle format, i need to save model in file .npy

Comment: What for? What do you need to do with the model?

Comment: i want to use my model (i have already trained )in Grad-CAM , so i need model in file .npy to load in code of Grad-CAM

Comment: What Grad-CAM implementation are you talking about? Have you seen the package keras-vis? It takes any keras model and provides different kinds of visualizations, including Grad-CAM. I feel you have an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to load a keras model saved as HDF5 (since you saved it with `model.save`)

```
self.data_dict = np.load(vgg16_npy_path, encoding='latin1').item()
```

The correct way is to use `keras.models.load_model`:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('your_file.hdf5')
```